# Why I cannot connect to server using selenium and spring?

Tags: java, spring, selenium

I can not connect to server under ssh.

I am using spring and selenium framework.

If I use putty for this task, it's all okay.

```
    SEVERE: Cannot connect to q1@srv01
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:490)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:162)
    at com.db.selenium.SSH.init(SSH.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.db.selenium.StartSelenium.main(StartSelenium.java:26)
```

property file:

```
ssh.url=srv01
ssh.port=22
ssh.username=q1
ssh.password=q1
```

May anyone know about my issue.

Thanks.

Edit, ver.1

main.xml file, which describes beans

```
<bean name="ssh" class="com.db.selenium.SSH" init-method="init">
            <property name="remotePlaybackPath" value="${ssh.playback.path}"/>
            <property name="session" ref="sshSession"/>
</bean>
```

java class

```
private void init() {
        log.debug("StrictHostKeyChecking = " + JSch.getConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking"));

        try {
            session.connect(); //exception
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            String msg = "Cannot connect to " + session.getUserName() + "@" + session.getHost();
            log.fatal(msg, e);
            throw new RuntimeException(msg, e);
        }

        if (remotePlaybackPath == null || remotePlaybackPath.length() == 0) {
            String msg = "Empty recording path";
            log.fatal(msg);
            throw new RuntimeException(msg);
        } else if (remotePlaybackPath.charAt(remotePlaybackPath.length() - 1) != '/') {
            remotePlaybackPath += '/';
        }
    }
```

Comment: there's not enough information here to provide an authoritative response...

Comment: окay, sorry, What may I give?  What info?

Comment: Java code would help.  Also, what's the relationship between your Spring server and Selenium?  Does your Spring server accept a request from HTTP, then run Selenium?

Comment: I added some info. May it will be useful.

Comment: May anyone know about my issue?